# Reverse engineering from SQLite database using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, sqlite

today I came across unsuccessfully in this issue: how to get the reverse engineering of a **SQLite** database into a UWP project with C#.

Following the link below, which works fine for CodeFirst, but I could not get the structure from the SQLite database using Scaffold-DbContext:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/uwp/getting-started

This is the command I wrote on the Package Manager Console:

**Scaffold-DbContext C:\MyDbName.db Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite  -outputdir /Models**

I hope someone has managed to solve this problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use the SQLite Toolbox in VS, and avoid adding design DLLs to your project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested by ErikEJ, I've installed the SQLite Toolbox, I've added a SQLIte connection, clicked with right mouse "generate code" .... so I get the code that represent my database.

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ErikEJ.SQLServerCompactSQLiteToolbox

Answer (score 2):

Creates a new context instance using agreements to create the name of the database to which the connection is established. Name agreement represents the full name (namespace + class name) of the derived context class.

Comment: Could you make an example because I don't understand. Tks

Answer (score 1):

This is rather old but I stumbled across the same problem today and this is how it works:

```
Scaffold-DbContext "Data Source=C:\MyDbName.db;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite -outputdir /Models
```

More information on correct connection strings: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/data/sqlite/connection-strings